# Difference between "Carry on" and "Carry on with"

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between the two? For example:

> 1. *Carry on the mission*
> 2. *Carry on **with** the mission*

Comment: ***carry on the*** seems to be more popular.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=carry+on+the%2Ccarry+on+with+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccarry%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccarry%20on%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: In some cases, *carry on with* means "have an affair" https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/carry_on

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the context, meaning, and message you are trying to convey.

"Carry on" IS the action.

I cannot believe the child would carry on like that in public.

"Carry on" on its own is a general command and is the same as "carry on with..."--one has less information and one has more.